# Variable variable Superglobals

Tags: php

In PHP ...

```
var_dump(${'_GET'});   // array(0) { } - #1

$var = '_GET';
var_dump(${$var});     // array(0) { } - #2

function test() {
  var_dump(${'_GET'}); // array(0) { } - #3
  $var = '_GET';
  var_dump(${$var});   // NULL - #4
}
test();
```

What happen?

Comment: There's also a warning generated for the one that outputs `NULL`: *E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: _GET*

Answer (score 12):

It's not a bug, [it's a feature](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

> #### Warning
>
> Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's
>   Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable
>   $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced
>   dynamically.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand this "warning" in the PHP docs, as it doesn't appear to be entirely correct, unless there is something else I've missed? The initial problem appears to be a scoping issue - as it would be with any (ordinary) global variable? If you simply include `global ${$var};` before `var_dump(${$var});` inside the function then it appears to work OK (tested PHP 5.2, 5.5). Have I missed something?

Comment: @w3d: The warning means that you can't `$$var` specifically when `$var` is `"_GET"` etc. It works as intended for all other variables.

Comment: Although you can if you call `global $$var` first, just as you would need to do for any _ordinary_ global variable.